# AWS Cloudfront Not Following Whitelist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

This is more of a general question to see if anyone has encountered similar behaviors with AWS Cloudfront. I've had a distribution running a static website with Geo-restrictions applied as follows:
[image: CloudFront Geo-Restriction Settings]

However, when looking at the logs, I see the following: 
[image: CloudFront Visitor Metrics]

So my question is - Is CloudFront monitoring ALL requests, even restricted ones? I would think Geo-restriction would implement an ACL and would block all requests at the network level before getting to the distribution to request data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront does not block geo-restricted requests at the network level. It serves a 403 response, which you can customize.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html

> CloudFront returns an HTTP status code of 403 (Forbidden) to the user.
>
> You can optionally configure CloudFront to return a custom error message to the user, and you can specify how long you want CloudFront to cache the error response for the requested file; the default value is five minutes.