# AWS Cloudfront block and allow list

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn, aws-billing

i have used cloudfront since years it was working fine till i got a huge traffic from specific countries.

i used Geographic Restrictions, and i have define block list to avoid any requests from specific countries, but after a while i found a huge traffic came to my CDN files from these countries!!!

then i have defined "allow list" to allow access CDN files from target countries and exclude other countries, but also this not work and i still getting huge traffic from other countries not in my allow list.

then i returned to define block list and mentioned the countries which i dont want. to block them, things was fine for somedays and no traffic came from there, but suddenly i found huge traffic again came from these countries even when it is mentioned in block list.

the issue here is how i can not control this even when AWS give this option "Geographic Restrictions" and allow traffic even when i block them. also regarding to this huge traffic the bill became too much bigger than other previous months and years!!.

anyone can help or explain it?

Comment: Could you confirm where you observe the origin of your traffic. Do you check the Report & Analytics console or the access logs?

Comment: yah sure, reports for usage and viewers shows the all of this traffic came from one country. and views report by device is "Bot/Crawler 90%". for few days block list was working and the report showed "1% for Bot/Crawler" and zero traffic from that counntry. later suddenly i got traffic from there even when it is on my block list.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485725/aws-cloudfront-not-following-whitelist) suggests blocked access are still part of the statistics. You should look at the error codes breakdown.